# How to Override glass mapper link?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, glass-mapper

I'm trying to solve one issue where i want to exclude folder from url. I already have the item resolver which takes care of the item, but glassmapper is picking up folder.

Im using glassmapper link get the url.

Updated : I've tried overriding GetItemUrl() as per below

```
   public override string GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item,Sitecore.Links.UrlOptions options)
    {  

        if(item.Parent!= null && item.Parent.TemplateID.Equals(AliasFolder))
        {
            var customUrl = base.GetItemUrl(item, options);
            return customUrl.Replace($"{LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item.Parent, options)}",string.Empty).ToLower();
        }

        return base.GetItemUrl(item, options); 
    }
```

Problem is if the item is at children level then it skips as im not checking for every parent. im trying to avoid loop to for every link  and checking for it parents. Is there a better approach i can try ?

Current strcutre

- Home

  - Folder

    - Item A
    - Item B

      - Item B1

Thanks

Comment: Glass mapper use `LinkManager` to generate links. `ItemResolver` is responsibly for translating url to Sitecore item. `LinkManager` is responsible for generating url. You need to override `LinkManager` or `LinkProvider`.

Comment: But this would only invoke when i use  link manager ? e.g LinkManager.GetItemUrl()

Comment: @CodeBox - it sounds like you replaced the OOTB ItemResolver with your own custom ItemResolver.   If that's the case, can you post the code for your custom ItemResolver?  We can then tell you how to override the LinkManager and/or LinkProvider.

Comment: Updated recent approach